# jquery: load html from a file without html-encoding entity text? (such as '{{>' for use with Handlebars partial templates)

Tags: jquery, html, templates, handlebars.js, partials

**Edit: found a solution**
Another user added a solution (that works) but then edited it, so I'm adding what I saw here for others:

The original template was in a `<div>` which is treated as text/html. I've replaced the `<div>` with this `<script>` and everything works as expected:

```
<script id="template-id" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

**Original posting**

I have all my Handlebars templates written out in separate html files. Until now I've used the following to load the source of the templates and expand them without a problem:

```
$.get(path,
    function(templates, textStatus, jqXhr) {
        var source = $(templates).filter(templateId).html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        /* ... */
```

The `source` then contains the template code. It has worked beautifully with simple templates. I even started using partials to add attributes to my html entities:

```
    <div class="pull-left label label-default tracking-item-data pointable"
         item-id="{{ItemId}}"
         data-id="{{Id}}"
         title="{{> tooltip}}">
        {{#if ExternalId}}{{ExternalId}}{{else}}Ignored{{/if}}
    </div>
```

That works fine.

However, now I'm adding a partial into the text of the entity (not just as an attribute) and things are breaking. Here's the template:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    {{#Data}}
    <li title="{{> tooltip}}">{{> datalabel}}</li>
    {{/Data}}
</ul>
```

When the `source` loads in my javascript above, it contains this instead of the expected value with proper Handlebars partial syntax:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    {{#Data}}
    <li title="{{> tooltip}}">{{&gt; datalabel}}</li>
    {{/Data}}
</ul>
```

Note how the `{{> datalabel}}` partial was encoded to `{{&gt; datalabel}}` when read from the `.html()` method.

It appears to me that partials in the entity text are being encoded. This breaks my Handlebars methods. How do I prevent the html from encoding when loading

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround: encode and then decode the `source` to pull out the proper html text. This fixes the issue and `{{&gt;` is decoded back to `{{>`. Here's the fix:

```
$.get(path,
    function(templates, textStatus, jqXhr) {
        var source = $(templates).filter(templateId).html();
        source = $('<div/>').html(source).text();

        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer but more of a bandaid on jquery/javascript. I'm still curious if any has a reason for why the original issue happens to begin with and how to avoid it.

Comment: Handlebars templates are text, not HTML. Why don't you use `$(templates).filter(templateId).text()`?